# A question about the proof $\dim(k[x_1,\dots,x_n]) = n$

Tags: maximal-and-prime-ideals, krull-dimension, polynomial-rings, integral-extensions

I am working on a proof of the Krull dimension of $K[x_1,\dots, x_n]$ for $K$ a field. I am stuck on the following step.

Suppose that $\dim(K[x_1,\dots, x_l]) = l$ and that the maximal chains of $k[x_1,\dots, x_l]$ have length $l$ for all $l<n$. Let $P_0\subset \cdots \subset P_m$ be a chain of prime ideals in $k[x_1,\dots, x_n]$. Without loss of generality, $P_0 = 0$ and $P_1$ is a minimal nonzero prime. Show that $k[x_1,\dots, x_{n}]/P_1$ is integral over $k[x_1,\dots, x_{n-1}]$.

My guess is that we need to argue that there is an element in $P_1$ with leading term $x_n$. Then, the result would be obvious.

Also, maybe it will add some context to some of the assumptions, but the next part is to show that if $Q_i = P_i/P_1 \cap k[x_1,\dots, x_n]$, then $Q_{i}\subset Q_{i+1}$ for all $1 \leq i \leq m$.

Comment: Do you know this result: if $k$ is a field and $f\in k[x_1,...,.x_n]$ is a nonconstant polynomial. There are elements $x_1',...,x_{n-1}'\in k[x_1,...,x_n]$ such that $k[x_1,...,x_n]$ is a finitely generated module over the $k-$algebra generated by $x_1',...,x_{n-1}'$ and $f$. If you know something about Noether Normalization.

Comment: @user782932 Yest, I have learned about Noether Normalization. However, I am unsure how it applies here.

Comment: You should first observe that $P_1=(f)$ is a principal ideal. Then maybe use the method in the proof or the direct result of Noether normalization.(or you can just apply the result I mentioned above)

Comment: Well, it is clear to me that $P_1 = (f)$ is a principal ideal. I see the idea of what you are trying to do with Noether Normalization, but can't quite get it to work out. I'll keep working at it though.

Comment: In the proof of Noether normalization, the change of coordinates should be involved. In this case, by changing coordinates, $f$ can be written as a monic in some $x_i'$